# Ctrl+C Store Clipboard to Variable C#

Tags: c#, copy, clipboard

I could use Sendkeys.Send("^c") to copy to clipboard.

How do I store the contents of the clipboard to a variable?

Comment: How about `Clipboard.GetData()`?

Comment: Seriously... You could easily find this out with google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on format:

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsAudio())
{
    var audio = Clipboard.GetAudioStream();
    [..]
}

if (Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList())
{
    var list = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
    [..]
}

if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
    var image = Clipboard.GetImage();
    [..]
}


if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html))
{
    var text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
    [..]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 string setText = "somedata"; 
 Clipboard.SetText(setText);//copy text from variable to Clipboard
 string getText=Clipboard.GetText();// copy text from Clipboard to variable
```